# Is this a GFCI tester on breaker panel? What does it do?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I noticed that there is a GFCI tester on the breaker panel. But I'm not sure what it was for. The directory just says "Ground Fault".

so I interact with it a little. I pressed the test button and heard a click sound. However when I push the switch to "ON" position nothing happens, and I heard no clicking sound. Further, when I pressed the test button again there's no clicking sound.

My questions are: what is the tester usually for on a breaker panel?
And should I be worried that the breaker does not seem to turn ON after testing?

Thank you!

[image: The GFCI tester on my electric panel]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking at there is a GFCI circuit breaker. Just like the other thing is a combination of outlet + GFCI, this is a combination of circuit breaker + GFCI.

A GFCI breaker protects the entire circuit from a ground fault and would replace the need for a GFCI outlet on the first outlet from the panel for that circuit.

The breaker should reset but to do so you must turn it all the way to the off position first and then turn it on. A tripped breaker will trip to the middle (between On and Off).

Comment: In case it's not apparent to the OP, the test button is the test for **that breaker** which provides GFCI protection to the entire circuit.

Comment: Emphasized what you are talking about. Other than that this answer is perfect.

Comment: And yes, the GFCI breaker doesn't need a reset button because, cycling the breaker "off, then on" serves as the reset button.

Comment: OP here. I can't seem to cycle the GFCI breaker "off then on" to turn the power back on. It seems unlikely that the receptacles are broken due my experiment. Is it possible that the breaker is broken??